# Order of growth rate in increasing order

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

> Arrange the following functions in increasing order of growth rate
>   (with g(n) following f(n) in your list if and only if f(n)=O(g(n))).

```
a)2^log(n)  
b)2^2log(n)  
c)n^5/2  
d)2^n^2  
e)n^2 log(n)
```

So i think answer is in increasing order is
CEDAB
is it correct? i have confusion in option A and B. 
i think option A should be at first place.. less one i mean so please help how to solve this.
This question I faced in algorithm course part 1 assignment (Coursera) .

Comment: This question seems not to be related to programming and is better suited for [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Think again, that's not correct.

Comment: I think http://cs.stackexchange.com would be the best place for this kind of question.

Comment: The question should be addressed in the respective Forum. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/778739/473461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, any positive power of `n` is *always* greater than `log n`, so E comes *before* C, not after.

Also, D comes after every other function, as either interpretation of `2^n^2` (could be `2^(n^2)` or `(2^n)^2 = 2^(2n)`; I could be wrong in ignoring BIDMAS though...) are exponentials of `n` itself.

Taking `log` to be base `a`, some arbitrary constant:

a) [image]

b) [image]

Thus, unfortunately, the actual order depends of the value of `a`, e.g. if the value of

[image]

is greater than 2, then A comes after E, otherwise before. Curiously the base of the log term in E is irrelevant (it still maintains its place).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `aecbd`

The easiest way to see why is to create a table with different values of n and compare amongst them. But some intuition:

`a` grows lesser than any others, specially `c` because of the log term in the power as opposed to the term itself

`e` is `a` with a n**2 term multiplied in, which is better than it being in an exponent

`b` is a double exponent, but still better than a quadratic power

`d` is the obvious worst because it grows exponentially with a quadratic power!